# If email exists force customer to login before ordering

Tags: checkout, orders, email, order-status, login

My current configuration is allowing customers to place orders without having to log-in on checkout,  even though they currently have accounts in the system, with the same e-mail we have stored for them,.  These orders they place without being logged in are therefore not viewable in their order history when they do log-in. Is there any way to require that they log-in if their e-mail address exists in the system, before ordering? I've been looking for a setting in the admin but to no avail.  I am using oneStepCheckOutAn. An admin setting would be preferred over having to insert validation code into the system, but anything helps! Thanks!

Comment: How does this behavior differ from disabling guest checkout?

Comment: He wants guest checkout but if the mail used for the order exists in the system they should be forced to log in. This is a security issue, because you are telling the attacker that the email exists. And no. This behavior is not included in the core.

Comment: @philwinkle: As Fabian mentioned, a guest should be able to checkout out without logging in, unless their e-mail address is already in our system. In which case the user should be forced to log-in.

Comment: Doing this actually also has the potential to drop conversion rates because if the user doesn't know they have an account already, they probably don't know what the password is. If you prevent the order unless they login, there is a pretty good chance they'll just go find it somewhere else.

Comment: @davidalger: Indeed it would, if we forced a guest to have an account. But we are looking for an option that would only force users that have created and account with us already to log-in. A guest user should be able to checkout as a guest as many times as they want. It's when they actually create an account that they should be forced to log in. Thanks!

Comment: If you ask me it is a better idea to send a link inside the order email and recommend to the user to add the order to his account. It should be quite easy, just send a link with a secret and order id and after login, add the customer_id to the order

Comment: Even the link can be abused. I would prefer an area of My Account where the customer enters some information about the order to verify that they placed the order. After that the order can be 'added' to their account.

Comment: @philwinkle How could the link be abused if the link included an HMAC signature of all the parameters to verify authenticity, as well as a hash-like key to identify the validity of the link through a lookup table? The HMAC eliminates the potential for users changing and/or creating their own similar URLs.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the solution you planned on, but I feel it is the better user experience (feel free not to accept this as an answer).

Based on my previous comments I have just open-sourced a module that achieves a similar result (guest orders linked to customers). However, in my module it allows a customer to associate a previous guest order to their account. This gives the power to the customer - if they want an order associated they have the ability to do so at a later date.

Based on Fabian and David's comments it may be a nice feature of the module to include an association link during the order confirmation if the customer meant to place the order under the registered account. David's feedback about how the link would work makes perfect sense and my fears about abuse have been allayed.

I hope that this module would be of some use for you as it was created in response to this thread.

https://github.com/philwinkle/Philwinkle_LinkGuestOrder

Best of luck.